10th Anniversary of Italian Language SE!
This month (November 2023) italian.stackexchange.com turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that you have found? What role has this site played in your Italian language learning journey over the years? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Congratulations to you all on 10 years. I'd like to thank Charo, egreg, and Denis Nardin for all you do as moderators on the site. On a personal note Italian Language SE has been such a wonderful source of help and knowledge for me. I had been studying Italian during the lockdown in 2020 and 2021 and the knowledge shared by this community was invaluable.
Grazie mille. Felice anniversario.
